# Homology of space $X=S^n \cup_f D^{n+1}$ where $f:S^n \rightarrow S^n$ has degree $m$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

The problem: Let $f:S^n \rightarrow S^n$ be a map of degree $m$. Let $X=S^n \cup_f D^{n+1}$ be the space attained from $S^n$ by attaching an (n+1)-cell via $f$. Compute the homology groups of $X$.

Could someone please check my solution?

$X$ has one 0-cell, one n-cell, and one (n+1)-cell. So $C_0(X)=\mathbb{Z}$, $C_n(X)=\mathbb{Z}$, and $C_{n+1}(X)=\mathbb{Z}$. All boundary maps must be zero except $\partial_{n+1}$, which is multiplication by $m$ since the boundary of the (n+1)-cell wraps around $S^n$ $m$ times.

Hence $H_{n+1}(X)=\ker\partial_{n+1}/\text{Im } \partial_{n+2}=0/0=0.$

$H_{n}(X)=\ker\partial_{n}/\text{Im } \partial_{n+1}=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ and
$H_{0}(X)=\ker\partial_{0}/\text{Im } \partial_{1}=\mathbb{Z}/0=\mathbb{Z}$.

So $H_k(X)$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ if $k=0$, $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ if $k=n$, and 0 otherwise.

Comment: You are impllcitly assuming that $n\ge2$. You have to do a little more work when $n=1$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Thank you! If $n=1$, X has one 0-cell and two 1-cells so $C_0=\mathbb{Z}$ and $C_1=\mathbb{Z}^2$. The boundary of one 1-cell is zero and the boundary of the other is multiplication by m. So $H_1=\mathbb{Z}^2/(0+m)=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$?